# NGINX proxy of SpringBoot websocket returns 400 due to "Upgrade Header: Null", Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, websocket

Im Running a default SpringBoot embedded Tomcat application server. From this server I serve a rest API and a websocket endpoint.

In front of this, a NGINX Proxy with the following config, is set up:

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

http {
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default Upgrade;
  ''      close;
 }

 server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  server_name  SERVER_NAME;
  root /var/www;



  underscores_in_headers on;


  location / {
   index index.html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;

   auth_basic "Restricted Content";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }

  location /api/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_pass http://SERVER_URL:9090/;
  }



  location /websocket {
   proxy_pass http://SERVER_URL:9090/websocket;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }



}
}
events{}
```

- The NGINX server serves a web application from the **/** location.
- It proxies to the REST API from the **/api/** location.
- And it proxies to the Spring boot websocket through the **/websocket** location.

Web application and REST API work without a problem.
But the websocket connection does not work. When I try to connect to the socket endpoint the following error is thrown on the tomcat application server.

```
 2018-07-17 11:53:05.516 ERROR 5 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler      : Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
```

So it seems that the upgrade header, which upgrades from HTTP to WS protocoll,
is not passed through to the application server. This should be solved by:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

But it does not work. If I try to connect to the websocket address directly, circumventing the NGINX, a connection is established succesfully.
My questions are:

- Is something missing in my NGINX configuration?
- Can somebody spot another error which could lead to the described behaviour?

Feel free to ask for more information about the system.

Comment: are you sure about the syntax of the config? in the documentation I've found: proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

Comment: sorry I found even the other... now I'm confused :)

Comment: Yeah, I also tried it using directly the "Upgrade" string. They way shown here, using a map to Upgrade, should not make a difference, I've seen both in the docs.

Comment: try `proxy_set_header Upgrade 'websocket';
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";`

Comment: Hi Guisong He, I added your suggestion. Now the 400 error is gone. But the connection times out after a long time with a 502 Bad Gateway and as far as I can tell from the App Server log, the request never arrives there.